# Is there any reason deflation would reduce profit?

Tags: macroeconomics

Profits are the difference between input and output prices. Is there any reason deflation would cause profits to decline generally rather than in those industries where output prices fell faster?

Answer (score 1):

Profits also depend on the quantity demanded/sold. If deflation is accompanied by a decrease in demand, under equal input/output price deflation (or even if input prices fall more than output prices), profits can fall.